# Как в WP задавать поля репитеры без покупки платных плагинов?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины, плагин

Как в WP принято задавать для страниц различные параметры типа перечислений разных сущностей (иконка+текст+описание), но без использования Elementor'a и платных плагинов типа AFC ?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: SO - это не форум. Тут один топик - один вопрос. Исправляй вопрос.

Comment: вторая часть это логичное продолжение первой. но раз тут там принято, удалил.

Comment: Помимо ACF, есть еще например [Carbon Fields](https://carbonfields.net/) он бесплатный.

Comment: Carbon Fields помог, спасибо.